# How to avoid quoting and escaping needed when passing commands and local variables to ssh with sudo?

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

How to avoid quoting and escaping needed when passing commands and local variables to ssh with sudo?

Found someone providing a creative way to avoid quoting by using here-documents. It sounded like a great idea, but it did not work for me in bash. Here is the advice I found: [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host "sudo su user -c $FOO" type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/quoting-in-ssh-host-foo-and-ssh-host-sudo-su-user-c-foo-type-constructs/102840#102840)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a basic bash script example.**

```
# Assign values to variables locally.
myvar1="myvalue1"
myvar2="myvalue2"
# Add your local commands here.

ssh myremotehost "$(
cat <<HEREDOC_EXPORT_VARIABLES
export myvar1="$myvar1"
export myvar2="$myvar2"
HEREDOC_EXPORT_VARIABLES

cat <<'HEREDOC_SUDO'
sudo -Eu root /bin/bash <<'HEREDOC_COMMANDS'

# Optionally display your variables.
echo "myvar1: $myvar1"
echo "myvar2: $myvar2"
# Add your remote commands here.

HEREDOC_COMMANDS
HEREDOC_SUDO
)" | tee logfile.log
```

**Explanation of different parts.**

Variables assigned values locally (before executing commands on remote machine):

```
myvar1="myvalue1"
myvar2="myvalue2"
```

`"$(` ... `)"` allow grouping multiple commands together and allow using double quotes within this block.

Export here-document block, which is not in single quotes, allows using local variables in the block:

```
cat <<HEREDOC_EXPORT_VARIABLES
...
...
HEREDOC_EXPORT_VARIABLES
```

Exporting of local variables to be available for remote commands.

```
export myvar1="$myvar1"
export myvar2="$myvar2"
```

Outer here-document block, which is in single quotes, to echo out sudo command and remove the necessity of escaping of remote variables for inner here-document (potentially may be replaced by `echo` without the line feed):

```
cat <<'HEREDOC_SUDO'
...
...
HEREDOC_SUDO
```

Inner here-document block, which is in single quotes, to remove the necessity of escaping of remote variables.

```
sudo -Eu root /bin/bash <<'HEREDOC_COMMANDS'
...
...
HEREDOC_COMMANDS
```

`-E` option in `sudo` allows preserving the environment variables, which were exported earlier.

`tee logfile.log` allows echoing output to terminal and to a log file at the same time.

As a bonus, you could replace `ssh myremotehost "$(` line with `echo "$(` and you will get an output of what your remotely executed part will look like for debugging purposes.

Tip: You may need to escape a non-paired single or double quote within `"$(` ... `)"` block, even if you use it in a comment.