# remote for loop with awk

Tags: bash, ssh, awk, for

I have a little program that gets the pids of 3 processes that are listening on different ports:

```
Admins-Mac-mini-2:~ gitlabuser$ for pn in 23 33 43; do lsof -nP -iTCP:47${pn} | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'; done
44171
44176
44181
Admins-Mac-mini-2:~
```

I want to run this little loop on a different machine so I tried backslashing the single quotes around the awk print like so:

```
Admins-Mac-mini-2:~ gitlabuser$ ssh gitlabuser@10.18.66.99 'for pn in 23 33 43; do lsof -nP -iTCP:47${pn} | grep LISTEN | awk \'{print $2}\'; done'
>
```

I also tried backslashing the $ :

```
Admins-Mac-mini-2:~ gitlabuser$ ssh gitlabuser@10.18.66.99 'for pn in 23 33 43; do lsof -nP -iTCP:47${pn} | grep LISTEN | awk \'{print \$2}\'; done'


>
```

It there a way to run that same command on both my local machine and the remote machine?

A

Comment: try `"{print \$2}"`

Comment: that works remotely but not locally

Comment: any way to get that for loop in such a way that itll work remotely or locally?

Comment: ... it should work locally as well

Comment: put it as an answer will you? so that I can accept it and you can get the points

Comment: It's likely already answered more comprehensively here: [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host “sudo su user -c $FOO” type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/quoting-in-ssh-host-foo-and-ssh-host-sudo-su-user-c-foo-type-constructs/4774#4774)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method

```
for i in remoteserverip
do
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $i <<'EOF'
for pn in 23 33 43
do
lsof -nP -iTCP:47${pn} | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'
done
EOF
done
```