# SSH Command on remote server

Tags: ssh, command, command-substitution

I'm stuck in a situation,

I run this command on node2

```
netstat -tlpna|grep `ps aux|grep tnslsnr|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`|head -1
```

and it works fine and gives me this output

```
tcp        0      0 10.6.1.22:1521          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2601/tnslsnr
```

But when i run this command from clinet machine to node2 it gives me error.

```
ssh  root@$(pcs status|grep oracle_LR|awk '{print $4}') 'netstat -tulpna $(ps aux|grep -v grep|grep tnslsnr'|awk '{print $2})'
```

[image]

## After Following from @steeldiver

I added double quote around awk and it is working

```
ssh root@$(pcs status|grep oracle_LR|awk '{print $4}') 'netstat -tulpna|grep $(ps aux|grep tnslsnr|grep -v grep|awk "{print \$2}")'|head -1
```

gives me this output

> tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1525          0.0.0.0:*
> LISTEN      2601/tnslsnr

**BUT**

when i add this line in my script.

[image]

```
$echo "<pre>`ssh root@$(pcs status|grep oracle_LR|awk '{print $4}') 'netstat -tulpna|grep $(ps aux|grep tnslsnr|grep -v grep|awk "{print \$2}")'|head -1`</pre>"
```

and when i run it gives me this output

```
grep: oracle: No such file or directory
grep: 2601: No such file or directory
grep: 0.0: No such file or directory
grep: 0.0: No such file or directory
grep: 227812: No such file or directory
grep: 18536: No such file or directory
grep: ?: No such file or directory
grep: Ssl: No such file or directory
grep: Aug27: No such file or directory
grep: 6:16: No such file or directory
grep: LISTENER: No such file or directory
```

I have been playing around with this but nothing is working

Comment: Related: [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host “sudo su user -c $FOO” type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/quoting-in-ssh-host-foo-and-ssh-host-sudo-su-user-c-foo-type-constructs)

Comment: It also appears you haven’t put enough single quotes in the ssh line.  There is one before the netstat at the beginning of the remote command, but the one at the end is for the ask statement.

Comment: can you please check the new edits in question

Comment: You should probably avoid all that nesting and try splitting your command into simpler pieces; as you can see, it is really hard to debug in its current state. Nevertheless, the errors from `grep` seem to say that it is getting a full line of output from `ps`, and the best candidate for that is `awk "{print \$2}"`: if the applied quoting is not enough, it easily becomes `awk "{print }"` (because there isn't a positional parameter n. 2 in the shell running it). _Maybe_ `awk "{print \\$2}"` is enough to avoid that error.

Comment: @fra-san, Tons of thanks i just added extra \ in awk like you mentioned, but i dont understand why do we have to add two \\ when using double quotes , my understanding was to use single \ when using $ sign within double quotes

Comment: That is because of the command substitution in backticks. It makes nesting harder because outer substitutions remove one level of backslashes in inner substitutions too. See, for instance, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082.