# Read command removes double space and keeps only one

Tags: scripting, read

I wrote a script that collects application logs on local machine and then from remote machine.

It has variable `oldlogsdate` which reads the date of logs I want to collect.

For example, if I enter `Apr 23` it works fine because there is only one space, but if I enter `Apr  4` (two spaces between `Apr` and `4`) it will remove one space.

Note: This `oldlogsdate` is also set on remote machine in user's `.bash_profile` and the entered date is then changed a using `sed` command.

```
printf "\n";read -p "Which Date Logs you want to collect = " oldlogsdate
ssh -qt remote-user-name@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "sed -i "s/oldlogsdate=.*/oldlogsdate=\'\"$oldlogsdate\"\'/" ~/.bash_profile"

oldlogsdate="Apr 7"
```

Now why I'm using `Apr 23` and `Apr  4` it's part of `ls` command.

Is there a way to retain double spaces in read command, or some other better way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Read command removes double space and Keeps only one

It doesn't. The `read` command by itself keeps the interior whitespace as is (however it will trim leading and trailing whitespace unless you set `IFS` to empty; it also will mangle backslashes if you don't use `-r`).

```
read myVar <<<'Apr  4'
echo "$myVar"  # will output: Apr  4
```

That's you who then lose spaces due to not double-quoting the variables:

```
myVar2='Apr  4'
echo $myVar2  # will mangle spaces, please always use "$myVar2" instead
```

Not quoting the variables properly not only makes the script misbehave but also may introduce potential security risks.

**A bit** more correct command would be

```
ssh -qt remote-user-name@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "sed -i 's/oldlogsdate=.*/oldlogsdate=\"$oldlogsdate\"/' ~/.bash_profile"
```

But it's not versatile and not safe anyway, because it doesn't take into account that the `$oldlogsdate` value can potentially contain not only spaces but also apostrophes, slashes, backslashes, dollar signs and exclamation marks.

Comment: Note that `read var` with the default value of `$IFS` strips leading and trailing space and tab characters.  See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: Thanks @sasha it really worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Note your `ssh` command line, the part with the `sed` command sent to the other end:

```
ssh ... "sed -i "s/oldlogsdate=.*/oldlogsdate=\'\"$oldlogsdate\"\'/" ~/.bash_profile"
        ^^^^^^^^^..................................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You have two quoted strings here, the ones marked with `^`. The rest in the middle is *not* quoted, and that includes the variable expansion `$oldlogsdate`. Since it's unquoted, it's subject to [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), and `Apr  7` becomes the two words `Apr` and `7`.  See also: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Now, `ssh` is smart enough to glue them back together, but by now the original amount of whitespace is lost, and it just adds a single space.

This is somewhat similar to how the shell forgets the original amount of whitespace in this and `echo` glues the words together with a single space:

```
$ echo hello  world
hello world
```

But note that with SSH, a single level of quotes doesn't help, since SSH passes the command line for the shell on the remote end to interpret, and in that shell too, extra whitespace between words is lost.

So this still doesn't work:

```
$ ssh localhost echo "hello  world"
hello world
```

(the local shell removes the quotes, and `ssh` gets `echo` and `hello  world`, and passes to the remote `echo hello  world`, which works as above.)

and we actually have to do quoting for both ends to keep the string intact:

```
$ ssh localhost 'echo "hello  world"'
hello  world
```

Actually, it would be better to use `printf ":%s\n" hello  world` etc. to show more properly where the words break, but the result is similar.

Switching the quotes so that the double-quotes are the outermost lets the local shell expand the variable, and leaves the single quotes for the remote, which minimizes the amount of expansions it does. You'll still need to backslash-escape any double-quotes you want to send to the other side.

```
$ greeting="hello  world"
$ ssh localhost "echo '$greeting'"
hello  world
```

That should work as long as the variable doesn't contain single-quotes itself. If it does, things get uglier, see: [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379181/escape-a-variable-for-use-as-content-of-another-script)

I think the command line in [@sasha's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646799/170373) looks like it should work for your case.

See also, e.g. this question: [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host "sudo su user -c $FOO" type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4770/170373)
The question at hand there has one *more* layer of processing, but the answers seem to apply for the "easier" case too.

Comment: Technically, it's not *word splitting* that happens on the remote shell, it's just normal syntax tokenisation there. *word splitting* generally refers to the separate process that happens when you leave work expansions (`$var`, `$(cmd)`, `$((arith))`) unquoted and involves the `$IFS` special parameter.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yep, rephrased a bit