# How to send expression with variables over ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, variable

I can run the followind loop locally

```
for i in A B C; do mycommand $i; done
```

Now I am trying to send it over `ssh`

The following version

```
ssh myhost for i in A B C; do mycommand $i; done
```

The following version

```
ssh myhost "for i in A B C; do mycommand $i; done"
```

also fails, because it wants `i` varibale locally.

How to handle?

---

Is there any general approach, for example, what if `mycommand` is another ssh?

```
ssh myhost 'for i in hos1 host2 host3; do ssh "$i" ... another for expression
```

Comment: [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host "sudo su user -c $FOO" type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4770/170373) -- better yet, don't pass the commands over the command line so you avoid the quoting hell completely

Comment: For Bash, but gives some insight: [How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690) A general approach can be summarized as (from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690)): "To be in control of what the remote shell will get as `$command_line_built_by_ssh`, you need to understand, predict and mastermind the parsing and interpreting that happens before. You need to craft your local command, so after the local shell and `ssh` digest it, it becomes the exact `$command_line…` you want to execute on the remote side."

Answer (score 6):

Just use single quote:

```
ssh myhost 'for i in A B C; do mycommand "$i"; done'
```

That will use the `$i` as literal characters to the ssh command instead of having the local shell substitute them. In general, you'll also want to double-quote the expansion to prevent issues with issues with word splitting, though it's not strictly necessary with the values here.

See:

- [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)

Comment: Hm, can't figure general approach, this is ad-hoc.

Comment: @Dims: the shell normally expands `$whatever` to replace it with the variable content *before* running the command. It also does so inside of double quotes like so: `echo "$PWD"`. Here, you want the shell to treat `$` as a literal symbol, and not expand it. Use single quotes like `echo '$PWD'` (try both commands!) or escape the `$` character: `echo \$PWD`.