# Preserve backslash when running sudo su test -c command

Tags: bash

I want to preserve the backslash in the variable SET_TEST_MSG when using it in `sudo su test -c [command]`.

When I run the following, I get `r1rnrnrnrrnr` instead of `\r1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\r\n\r`:

```
SET_TEST_MSG='\r1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\r\n\r'
sudo su test -c "/usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c \"echo $SET_TEST_MSG; exec bash\""
$PROG -n $PICKVM 0 -1 -d "$SET_TEST_MSG"
```

How do I preserve the backslash when running `sudo su test -c [command]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking `su` to run the command through a shell, and then running another shell to go. You'll need to make sure to escape everything properly for the inner shell to see the command you want it to see.

This is similar to the case here: [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host "sudo su user -c $FOO" type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/quoting-in-ssh-host-foo-and-ssh-host-sudo-su-user-c-foo-type-constructs)

However, I'm not sure why you're running `sudo` and `su -c` there, when you could just do the same with `sudo`, removing one shell and making the escaping much easier:

```
msg='\r1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\r\n\r'
sudo -u test /usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c "echo '$msg'; exec bash"
```

Alternatively, put the innermost command in a script file, and run that instead. (Just make sure the target user can run the script.)

```
$ cat > /tmp/msgshell.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
msg='\r1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\r\n\r'
echo "$msg"
exec bash
EOF
$ chmod 755 /tmp/msgshell.sh
$ sudo -u test /usr/bin/screen -dmS test /tmp/msgshell.sh
```